# Laravel 8 Image intervention: Can't write image data to path

Tags: laravel, image, resize, intervention

This is how I'm trying to use `image intervention` package:

```
public function saveImage(string $path, $image)
{
        $file = $image;

        $filename = Str::random(20) . $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $imgResize = Image::make($image);
        $imgResize->heighten(300);

        //dd(is_writable(storage_path('app/public/'.$path)));

        $imgResize->save(storage_path('app/public/'.$path));


        return $destination_path = Storage::disk('local')->put('/'.$path, $image);    
}
```

The image is saved successfully without using image intervention. When I try to `save()` it it will throw me this error:

`Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException: Can't write image data to path`.

I have already changed the permissions of the folder, but still not working.

Any idea what is causing this?

Edit:

I did earlier `php artisan storage:link` and that's why it works without using image intervention.

I did `dd(storage_path('app/public/'.$path));` which results in the same folder in which the normal images are saved successfully.

I also checked if `is_writable` and the result is `true`.

Just for testing purposes I already changed the permissions to `777`.

I don't know what else to do to make this work.

Comment: what's in the $path ?

Comment: The name of the folder : `review_images`

Comment: If I try to save it to somewhere else like : `$imgResize->save(storage_path('app/public/'.$filename));`  it works.

If I try to save it to `$path` it will throw the same error again.

The problem is that I'm using this method inside a service which works for many other services/controllers and I get the `$path` dynamically so I cannot do this: `$imgResize->save(storage_path('app/public/folder_name'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the file name in the `save()` method

```php
$imgResize->save(storage_path('app/public/'.$path.'/'.$filename));
```

here some examples from the documentation of [intervention site](http://image.intervention.io/api/save)

> // open and resize an image file
> $img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);
>
> // save file as jpg with medium quality
> $img->save('public/bar.jpg', 60);
>
> // save the same file as jpg with default quality
> $img->save('public/baz.jpg');
>
> // save the file in png format
> $img->save('public/bar.png');
>
> // save the image jpg format defined by third parameter
> $img->save('public/foo', 80, 'jpg');

Comment: Thanks bro. You are my savior today :P

Comment: @MarinarioAgalliu you're welcome, sometimes when you think too much about an issue you forget to check simple stuff :)

Comment: Yeah bro, you know sometimes you get focus more on the problem than on the solution. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

the save method actually needs absolute path or path relative to the file in which the method is used. so give a filename, with all parent folders already created. use `storage_path()`, `public_path()`, or `base_path()` (or other method laravel provides). or any method from core php.